# Security risk if allowing all file type extensions on user uploads

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, file-upload

**Background:** I have a website where people can store transactions. As part of this transaction, they could attached a receipt if they wanted.

**Question:** Is there any security risk if a user is allowed to upload any type of file extension to my website?

**Info:**

- The user will be only person to ever re-download the same file
- There will be no opportunity for the user to "run" the file
- They will only be able to download it back to themselves.
- No other user will ever have access to another users files
- There will be a size restriction on the say (say 2mb)

**More info:** I was originally going to restrict the files to "pdf/doc/docx" - but then realised some people might want to store a jpg, or a .xls etc - and realised the list of files they "might" want to store is quite large...

**edit:** The file will be stored outside public_html - and served via a "readfile()" function that accepts a filename (not a path) - so is there anything that can 'upset' readfile()?

Comment: A file extension is pointless - It doesn't _really_ tell you anything about the file, especially since it can be easily changed by the user.

Comment: make sure you do basic sanitization so the users can't make filenames like "myimage/../../../php.ini"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely a security risk unless you take precautions. Lets say, to re-download the file, the use has to go to `example.com/uploads/{filename}`. The user could upload a malicious PHP file, and then 'redownload' it by going to `example.com/uploads/malicious.php`. This would, of course, cause the PHP script to execute on your server giving him enough power to completely wreck everything.

To prevent this, create a page that receives the filename as a parameter, and then serve the page to the user with the correct `content-type`.

Something like, `example.com/files?filename=malicious.php`

Comment: -1 [Server configurations](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/disable-php-apache-htaccess/) can prevent executing PHP files in `/uploads/`. Simply accessing a URL ending in `.php` **does not** mean any PHP code will be executed.

Comment: Of course server config can prevent execution. That would be one way of preventing execution. I simply provided a different way. There are other ways as well (such as via an `.htaccess` file)

Comment: Not everyone have access to the server configurations. at least on my servers i do not give that rights to my developers. so even if configurations can do so, i would expect the program to also sanitise the data.

Comment: Also, server configs can go awry sometimes. Better to have both measures in

Comment: thanks Xbonez - I should have mentioned the file is servered via readfile() from a location outside the public_html location - so they cant "run" the php AFAIK? I'll edit my question now

Answer (score 3):

"There will be no opportunity for the user to "run" the file"

As long as you are 100% sure that that will hold true, it is secure.  However, make sure the file will not be able to be executed by the webserver.  For example, if the user uploads a .php file, make sure the server does not execute it.

Computers don't run programs magically by themselves, so basically you just need to ensure that the user has no ability to trick your server into running the file.  This means making sure the proper handlers are disabled if the files are under the web root, or passing them through a proxy script if they are not (basically `echo file_get_contents('/path/to/upload')` with some other logic)

Another option would be to store the file like `name.upload` but this would require keeping a list of original names that map to the storage names.

Comment: actually one can append custom extension (not replace it) and then there should be no need to keep the list of original names. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Oh wow...  I should have realized that.  That is indeed correct.